# SP2010: possible to override styling of the upload aspx dialog from calling parent page

Tags: client-object-model, css, file-upload, dialog-framework

This may be a silly question, but I am wondering if it's possible to override styles for the upload.aspx dialog to customize the look...not from the upload pages content but form the calling 'parent' page? I don't think it is since I believe that it is a iframe and I assume you can't do this with a iframe but I am not really sure. Have customized look and feel collection of pages I did with ecma/designer but I am stuck with the OOB look of the upload form itself?

To be clear I don't want to mess with the upload page itself because I have read its not a great idea, and I don't want to change functionality, just styles....

Thanks as always

Comment: May be, you can inject css into that dialog use 'window' object

Comment: that's cool, now I just need to figure out how to do that. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject a css file into that dialog use some code like this:

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframeId');    
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "http://example.com/mystyle.css";
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345003/can-i-inject-a-css-file-programmatically-using-a-content-script-js-file) for detail.